# how to feed input node (which is a sentence) in android studio using TensorFlowInferenceInterface

Tags: java, android-studio, tensorflow, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

If my question is unclear, please let me know, I am quite new in this area.

I did the following:

1. I freezed and optimized tensorflow model
2. It is a RNN lstm model , getting a sentence then saying if that positive or negative
3. I successfully added all the things in android studio
4. Now I have a editbox to enter my sentence , then touch Run button, then this run button should fill the label if this sentence was positive or negative,

Would you please give me some instructions that if there is a predefined function I should use,
or I have to write down that by myself, if this is the case, how,

Thanks in advance for helping.

**Update**

This is something I have tried but it seems quite incorrect:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    inferenceInterface = new TensorFlowInferenceInterface();
    inferenceInterface.initializeTensorFlow(getAssets(), MODEL_FILE);


    final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            final EditText editNum1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editNum1);

            inferenceInterface.fillNodeInt(INPUT_NODE, INPUT_SIZE, editNum1);

            inferenceInterface.runInference(new String[] {OUTPUT_NODE});

            int[] resu = {0, 0};
            inferenceInterface.readNodeInt(OUTPUT_NODE, resu);

            final TextView textViewR = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtViewResult);
            textViewR.setText(Float.toString(resu[0]) + ", " + Float.toString(resu[1]));
        }
    });
}
```

**Edit2**

there is FillNodeInt in TensorFlowInferenceInterface, 
what I thought is that, it is going to tie my input in the editbox to the input node in my model,

so the first parameter is input node, the second is the size, and the third should be the input for example I fill in the text box,

but there is no function to have the third parameter as String,
 they are int or float or byte(like example above which is Int), or something like buffer
can someone please explain which method I can use

Comment: Does your RNN model take a raw string as input? (In other words, what is the TensorFlow datatype of the INPUT_NODE?). What is the shape of the input node (is it a single string, or a batch of strings)?

The recommendation on how to feed would depend on the answers to these questions

(As an aside, it seems you're using an older version of the TensorFlowInferenceInterface API, there is no `fillNodeInt` or `readNodeInt` at head anymore, just `feed` and `fetch`)

Comment: thanks @ash for your comment , actually my model is this https://github.com/rvinas/sentiment_analysis_tensorflow , can you please have a look on that,

Comment: Actually I can now tell the detail but there is a good detail in the first page, Readme, takes 1 min too look at , if your are not comfortable I can answer here

Comment: It's hard to determine what exactly you're trying to do looking at a whole github repository, it would be best if you added the relevant information to your question.

Assuming you were trying to do what `predict.py` in the linked repository is doing, it seems that the `input` node there expects an int32 tensor, not a string (`print input.dtype` added in `predict.py`). So if you're doing that, doesn't look like you need to feed strings

Comment: It seems it is using a picked vocabulary file (https://github.com/rvinas/sentiment_analysis_tensorflow/blob/edc345b8bee3756f5034d75df8f0302ed095126f/tsa/data_manager.py#L52)

Comment: thanks @ash for your explanations, I explained a bit in my question, the model for training is freezed, no need to use predict file anymore I guess, so as expected , it goes through a tweet then give if it is positive or negative, but I think you are right the input is batch in int, but I dont know how to do it, also there is no documentation

Comment: The input to your model seems like it will be a list of integers where each integer represents the vocabulary lookup for a string word. Freezing the model doesn't change the fact that the model expects a tensor of integers as input and that the vocabulary lookup needs to be done outside the model.

Not quite sure what documentation you're looking for. The documentation for TensorFlowInferenceInterface talks about how to feed different types of data to a model. The details of the model you're using (datatypes of inputs/outputs) would be out of scope for TensorFlowInferenceInterface

Comment: @ash thank u also very much for ur comprehensive explanations, from ur comment I learned that I cannot do that just till night, as if needs just an array of int, it would be achievable but combining with other concept in android studio, I didnt think it may take time :( ... one more thing about the documentation , u mean in documentation they mention how to feed a RNN model generally, i would expect that, then by myself applyyin other things

Comment: It proved to be hard, in each step errorrs , why no one has done something like this, it seems very general. ACTUALLY if the input should be an array of ineger how I am able to convert string to int in android studio part???